# SMTP issue sending mail from a specific account

Tags: dovecot, exim

SMTP has been working perfectly for months, I have there 2 domains, first one has many accounts, and works without any use, the second domain has only 1 account, and till now it has been also working perfectly.

that account can receive mails but attempting to send a mail fails (using thunderbird), using roundcube works perfectly :/

I got: Local temporary error, please try again later

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Yeah, I monitorized exim/maillog, exim/rejected and dovecot.log but there isn't too much to see, just the login session when I log in at dovecot.log